# Add up sum of time in android SQLite database

Tags: android, sql, database, timestamp, timestamping

I have a database that time stamps every five minutes, or less if the user stops the database. How can I take the sum of the difference between the time stamps and add them up?

**EDIT**

I have six different times all five minutes apart and one time the is, lets say, only 2 minutes from the last logged auto time that have been logged by the user:

13:41:33

13:46:33

13:51:33

13:56:33

14:01:33

14:06:33

14:08:27

now I want to take the times and add a mark that says its how many minutes from the last logged time:

13:41:33 = 0 //will be zero cause that is where the user started timing

13:46:33 = 5

13:51:33 = 5

13:56:33 = 5

14:01:33 = 5

14:06:33 = 5

14:08:27 = 2

After that I want my application to take all the fives and the twos and add them up:

0 +

5 +

5 +

5 +

5 +

5 +

2 =

27 minutes

Comment: Could you give an example of what your table looks like and what the results you'd like look like?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, I have added what I want if you need any more info just ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a SQL `SUM` function on that column and it should give you your result. You should probably tag your question with more specific tags (SQLite, SQL, Etc)

Comment: Could I have an example of the `SUM` function?

Comment: I forgot to mention that you're going to need to truncate the data. For example 14:08:27 will need to be 08:27 and then you can subtract accordingly. Once you do that to each row, you will then take the SUM

Comment: I keep getting an error saying no such column: SUM: , while compiling: SELECT SUM JobTime FROM wwlltdTable my query looks like return ourdb.rawQuery("SELECT SUM "+KEY_TIME+" FROM " + WW_LLTDTABLE , null); KEY_TIME is set as numeric

Comment: Also I have tried Cursor c =  ourdb.rawQuery("SELECT "+KEY_ROWIDLATLON+" SUM"+"("+KEY_FIVEMINUTES+")"+" FROM " + WW_LLTDTABLE , null);
   return c; and it says that the error is now near `(`

Comment: So I did get it working I had to have my constructor a double instead of a cursor. Thank you for your time